# Link to download file not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, hyperlink

I am trying to get a link to download a file (there's a class reference to bootstrap on the button. The code I have works but only for Chrome. I need it to also work with Firefox and IE browsers.

This is the code I have:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><a style="color:#fff;" target="_blank" href="http://pathtodirectory/FileName.ext" >
     Download</a></button>
```

I tried adding

```
download
```

but that did not work.

Any ideas why this only works in Chrome? And a good way to implement it to work in IE and Firefox?

Thank you!

Comment: Why you mix button and a tags? You need simply one a tag with style of button. This is css nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to have a button element, just use the classes on the anchor element instead.

```
<a style="color:#fff;" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" target="_blank" href="http://pathtodirectory/FileName.ext">Download</a>
```